# Finding Multiple arrtibutes Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, attributes

Ok so I want to find all the images on a page, which I do like this:

```
x = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
```

But I want the 'src' attribute for everything that is returned. But I can't seem to be able to return the attributes for all the elements, only when I change the code to `find_element` (singular) does it work.
Does anyone know how to get all the attributes in this way? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a *List* of the desired elements and then extract the *src* attributes and append them within a *List* as follows:

```
src_list = []
x = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
for element in x:
    src_list.append(element.get_attribute('src'))
print(src_list)
```